# Bug in search results

Tags: support, search

I ran the following search:

> [[bash] or [awk] answers:0 score:0+ closed:no](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bbash%5D%20or%20%5Bawk%5D%20answers%3A0%20score%3A0%2B%20closed%3Ano)

However, the top result there shows a score of -1, which is a contradiction of my requirement `score:0+`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm gonna assume that it only just got downvoted and the search index is taking a few minutes to be synched with SQL Server. It's the afternoon in the US, maybe a lot of people are voting

Comment: The downvote happened a while back.  But let's wait and see if it disappears.  How long do you expect to have to wait?

Comment: It's maybe also that the operator `score:0+` doesn't actually exist. `score:0` is the operator that describes what you were trying to do. It returns different results.

Comment: You are correct-- SO recognizes that this post has a non-zero score, and doesn't show it in the results when I type `score:0`.  However, typing that removes posts with scores 1,2,3,etc.  Is there a way to include them in my search?

Comment: Not that's an interesting question. The advanced search tips (top right when you search says that `score:0` _is_ 0+. However, the normal way of representing that would be `score:0..`. Clicking on the help page (bottom of the tips) confirms this. It appears as though the search tips are incorrect...

Comment: Report *that* as a bug.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not working because `score:0+` is not a valid search. Look how "score" is not listed on the right:

> [image]

You want to use `score:0..`, like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+or+%5Bawk%5D+answers%3A0+score%3A0..+closed%3Ano).